# How to reinforce a flimsy settee?

Tags: furniture

we have a Settee that does not feel very sturdy. It is rated at 250 lbs and there is a slight wobble. What can I do to make it steadier and more load bearing? (e.g. 400lb)

Here is the settee: http://www.wayfair.com/Skyline-Furniture-Velvet-Settee-Loveseat-I-6006-SKY1440.html

Here are the instructions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/loc5Q.jpg

Structually, it's essentially two solid wood sides and a bench held together by four 5/16th bolts.

Am I right in thinking that the legs are the weak point?

Comment: Note that couch weight limits are typically listed on a **per-seat** basis.  Your settee should safely hold **two** people who are each up to 250lbs.  If your family is bigger than this you generally need to shop for furniture specially designed for larger people.  Augmenting the structure would, of course, be possible, but it's altogether easier and cheaper to just buy the right thing to start.

Comment: Adding another pair of legs in the centre would probably be the easiest, but it's likely even the [internal bracing](https://designbigger.com/what-is-the-weight-capacity-of-an-average-couch/) would need to be augmented. (link for an example of how these things can fail internally when overloaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the instructions, it appears that there are six washers and nuts holding it together. If you only used four, that might be a problem. ;)

I would go back over the piece, checking the tightness of the nuts. Side-to-side motion is likely a problem with the nuts, not the legs.

Comment: Haha yes, I did use all 6 washers and nuts. I will check the tightness again. Any suggestions for the fact that it is rated to be only 250 lbs weigh limited?

Comment: Not any suggestions that don't involve getting into upholstery. You could conceivably get into the settee and add internal bracing, but then you'd have to fix the appearance of those repairs, etc. (If you're actually interested in that kind of thing, I can highly recommend the 'Furniture Guys' book on repair.

Comment: Time to go to the library!